Intermittent sound issues
I have sound issues on RPi 5 (Bookworm 64bit, original charger) that only happen when I boot RPi while the TV it is connected to (via HDMI 0) is turned off: after turning the tv on, I would hear no sound, there would be no sound icon on the taskbar, pavucontrol will only show the dummy interface, and raspi-config will not show anything when entering audio options.
Once I reboot the rpi with the tv on, everything goes back to normal.
So far I tried adding:
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2

in /boot/firmware/config.txt but it didn't change anything. I also looked at the dmesg logs and lsmod but they don't differ in these two settings (lsmod not loading snd_bcm2835 (loading it doesn't change anything), dmesg seeing vc4-hdmi registered as audio devices).
Any idea how to convince rpi to initialize audio even if the tv is not on while it was booted?

Is this Pi OS Bookworm 64bit, fully updated? HDMI audio?

correct, hdmi 0 (close to usb port), original charger

Update your question with these details. Try a fresh install on a spare sd card.

I might try if I get a spare sd card but I kinda hoped someone would be able to point me to something that could be wrong without deleting everything ^^
